# Link to index and trigger specific ajax load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a site where the index.php is a DOM that has various links in the menu.

```
<li><a class="book" href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
<li><a class="kontakt" href="#contact">contact</a></li>
```

Every link loads the content of a div via ajax. (and in my case a little animation).

What if I want to redirect from another site to my index.php but then already load the div via ajax from contact.php directly?

Just using www.domain.com/#contact does not work.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.kontakt').on('click', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
        $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'0' }).empty();
    }
    $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'650px' },function() {
        $('#loader').css({ border:'none', position:'relative', top:'24px', left:'48px', boxShadow:'none' }); 
        $('#ajax').load('kontakt.php ' + href, function() {
            $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});});
```

Comment: research how to parse url hash

Comment: I'm not sure that is how it would work for me.  I thought of using some kind of onlick post function?

Comment: several  ways can use it...you can try using hash to trigger a clcik, very simple selector since it matches href of your link or more robust is move the clcik handler code into a function and call that function as callback to the clcik handler or from hash parsing code

Comment: that sounds like what I need, but I have no idea how to do that :/

Comment: copy those 3 words into google for a start. Paste this into a browser console where on page you have a hash in url `alert(location.hash)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library such as [jQuery.bbq](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) to enable hash-based linking. I don't know enough about your source code to provide a customized example, so here is the official one: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic.